# How to create an array from a csv file in python

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I have a csv file with a list like this:

12, 1233, 234

12, 1233, 989

12, 9898, 213

14, 1233, 987

14, 1233, 876

I want to make an array for the rows which are similar. for example in the above example, i want make an array of which is like this: 12, 1233 [234, 989] since the values in their first two rows are same

```
import csv with open('check.csv', 'r') as csvfile: 
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',') for row in reader:
         print(re.search( #uniqueSet = list(set(x))
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to write some code, then. Did you have a question?

Comment: import csv
with open('check.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
 reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
 for row in reader:
  print(re.search(

#uniqueSet = list(set(x))                         am struck there

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show a [mcve]; what does *"stuck"* mean?

Comment: What happens when is only one like 12, 9898, 213, do you want the row or not?

Comment: @Merlin Ah, can't see that from the mobile app, sorry.

Comment: @Merlin Yes i need everything which is unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do most of the work for you

```
#read the csv file
with open('csv_file.csv','r') as f:
   lines=[l.split(',') for l in f.readlines()]
#Aggregate by the 3rd field by the first two fields
import collections    
d=collections.defaultdict(list)
for l in lines:
   d[(l[0],l[1])].append(l[2])
```

The csv (`csv_file.csv`) file would be read as a dictionary (variable `d`), all you have left is to transform it to a list or whatever format you want

Comment: import csv
import collections 
with open('file.csv','r') as f:
#lines=[l.split(',') for l in f.readlines()]
        reader = [l.split(',') for l in f.readlines()]

d=collections.defaultdict(list)
for l in reader:
        d[l[0]+':'+l[1]].append(l[2])

uniqueSet = list(set(l))
print(d)   this works!

Comment: If my answer was helpful please accept it or at least vote up

Comment: Hi yes! i accepted it , but i am unable to vote it up since i need 15 points to vote.. :)